# Custom Camera Not working on Motorola Device

Tags: android

I just make an app in android in which i am using the custom camera.The whole app is working fine in all the versions of samsung devices.But the custom camera is not working properly in Motorola device.Can any one help me to solve this issue??Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

have faced problems specially with Motorola

hope it will help you